# Rails ajax update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to change a Workorder.wostatus_id based on data in html.

In my index html, I have the wostatus.id stored like this:

```
<span id="woid">4</span>
```

I would like to update the workorder.wostatus_id = 4

This is in the workorders.js.coffee - but, it's not working:

```
   $.ajax
     type: 'POST'
     url: 'http://localhost:5000/workorders'
     data:
       workorder:
         wostatus_id: $("#woid").val()
```

Maybe I'm not getting to the right workorder record?

Even doing this didn't update the workorder.wostatus_id

```
     $.ajax
       type: 'POST'
         url: "http://localhost:5000/workorders"
       data:
         workorder:
           wostatus_id: '3'
```

This didn't work either:

```
     $.ajax
      type: 'POST'
      url: "http://localhost:5000/workorder/17"
      data:
        wostatus_id: '7'
```

I'm missing something big time.

Does the ajax POST execute this code in the workorder controller????

```
 # PUT /workorders/1
 # PUT /workorders/1.json
 def update
  @workorder = Workorder.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
  if @workorder.update_attributes(params[:workorder])
    format.html { redirect_to @workorder, notice: 'Workorder was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :ok }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @workorder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

UPDATE:

I added this to the workorder controller:

```
 def changestatus
  @workorder = Workorder.find(params[:id])
  @workorder.update_attribute :wostatus_id, '4'
  render nothing: true
 end
```

I added this to the routes:

```
  resources :workorders do
   member { put :changestatus }
  end
```

This is currently in the js.coffee:

```
  $.ajax
    type: 'PUT'
    url: "http://localhost:5000/workorders/11/changestatus"
    data:
      wostatus_id: 4
```

(I'm hard coding things until I get the next step working.)

SO - this works, workorder 11 gets wostatus_id changed to 4.

But, now I'm having trouble getting the right information from the html.
The html contains 2 data fields I need - one for which workorder and the other is what the wostatus_id is.

Here is the html for the update url:

```
<div class="false" data-change-url="http://localhost:5000/workorders/16/changestatus">
```

I thought this would get that url - but, it doesn't work:

```
$(this).data('change-url')
```

Comment: `update` action code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out I didn't need any new controller code - I could just use update.
This is for jquery-ui sortable.

```
   receive: (event, ui) ->
     str_id =  $(ui.item).attr('id')
     woid = str_id.split('_')[1]
     $.update "/workorders/" + woid,
       workorder:
         wostatus_id: $(this).data('wostatus-id')
```

Thanks for the help - you got me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, then I think your sending a single value while your controller expects an array, and you're using different param names (`wostatus_id` on client, `workorder` on server).

Perhaps what you want is this:

```
$.ajax
  type: 'POST'
  url: $('#sort2').data('update-url')
  data:
    workorder: $('#sort2 span').map((i, el) ->
      el.text()
    ) // Change the selector to the elements that holds the ID
```

Comment: You know we can't really figure it out without knowing what happens at the controller and probably the model behind it, would please post these related code?

Comment: I added the controller code - I think.  I don't understand which controller def the POST executes.

Comment: Take a look in the app's logfile. It will tell you, which action is triggered (Look out for something like "Started POST ...")

Comment: POST requests normally are mapped to update. `wostatus_id` is a foreign key, right? If so, are you using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for the the relation?

Comment: Ahmad - I got the controller and restful routing working.  But, now I'm having trouble getting values from the html into the javascript.  Please look at my updated question.  Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the context you're calling your JS in, I know I ask too much, but do you mind posting the complete JS so that I can figure out what is `this`?